# sum of column in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysqli, codeigniter-3

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object

```
$query = $this->db->query("Select count(id) as count From `bookings` where status=6");
$row = $query->row('bookings');
echo $row->count;
```

Comment: is `$this` a class? if so, then `$row` isn't. `var_dump($query, $row);` and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this code, it will return all row numbers, if no data found then return no data found.

```
$query = $this->db->query("select count(id) as count From bookings where status=6");
  if($query->num_rows() > 0 )
  {
     $row =  $query->row();
     echo  $row->count; // return the count
  } else {
      echo 'no data found';
  }
```

or you can use `num_rows()`

```
$query = $this->db->query('select count(id) as count From bookings where status=6');
echo $query->num_rows();
```

hope it will help you